# Blender 2.8 / Windows 10 / Python - import Module fails, pip install Module fails, pip install Wheel fails

Tags: python

I need to use the VTK module in a python script inside Blender.  It seems that there is no Python 3.7 version of VTK for Intel chips (and B2.8 comes with P3.7) and so I'm now trying to figure out if I need to downgrade blender, python, both, ***or if some other (better) solution exists.***

Running Windows 10 (sadly...certainly not by choice)

Comment: PyPI has a package for Windows 64 Bit and Python 3.7 https://pypi.org/project/vtk/#files

Comment: Ah, yes, but how to install on an Intel based machine...

Comment: Through `pip install`? If your question was regarding amd64, it's called like that for historic reasons. It's the right package for 64 bit independent of the CPU manufacturer.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` + `pip install vtk` = `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk`

Also, 
`python -m ensurepip` + `python -m install vtk1` results in the same.  I thought it might be an architecture problem but it seems to be something else...

Trying from wheel: `python -m pip install 'wheellocal.whl'`  = `ERROR:  vtk-8.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: I just tested this in a venv and it works fine. Please check that you're actually running Python 3.7. (`python --version`) and ensure that it's a 64 bit install of Python.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem was, but thank you for your help.  I think this was an admin / not using the right pip problem.  I've added the solution to answers.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the reinstall and admin rights are necessary for all cases but the following solved my problem:

1. Uninstall Blender and reinstall as Admin
2. In Blender Python shell run

   ```
   import sys
   sys.exec_prefix
   ```
3. Open Powershell as Admin
4. Go to directory listed by Blender Python shell
5. Ensure pip

   ```
   .\bin\python.exe -m ensurepip
   ```
6. Install modules

   ```
   .\Scripts\pip3.exe install vtk
   ```

Thanks to @rgj for troubleshooting and [this blog for Blender/pip instructions](http://www.codeplastic.com/2019/03/12/how-to-install-python-modules-in-blender/)